# What is the best way to parse an XML boolean attribute (in .NET)?

Tags: .net, xml, .net-2.0, boolean, xml-attribute

An XML attribute declared as xs:boolean can acceptable be "true", "false", "0" or "1".  However, in .NET, Boolean.Parse() will only accept "true" or "false". If it sees a "0" or "1", it throws a "Bad Format" exception.

So, given that, what's the best way to parse such a value into a Boolean?

(Unfortunately, I'm limited to .NET 2.0 solutions, but if v3.5 offers something, I'd love to hear about it.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I think that [XmlConvert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2104c2x.aspx) has all the methods for converting between common language runtime types and XML types. Especially [`XmlConvert.ToBoolean`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.toboolean.aspx) handles exactly the boolean values (valid strings are "1" or "true" for true and "0" or "false" for false).

Comment: Excellent.. Exactly what I was looking for (knew I should have spent more time poking through the .Net Library Reference)

Comment: Be wary of values like True and False, which XmlConvert views as invalid boolean values.  You cannot simply fix this with a simple ToLower() either because XmlConvert throws an exception for any value it does not recognize.  XmlConvert is not a silver bullet, but instead it is an interesting tool.

Comment: @OwenIvory Values like True and False are indeed invalid boolean values according to XML Schema specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean. See also the discussion in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308491

Answer (score 2):

Using `CBool` instead of `Boolean.Parse` should do the trick: although you'll have to embed it in a `try/catch` block (which wouldn't be required when using `Boolean.TryParse`), it will successfully convert most 'sensible' boolean values, including true/false and 0/1.

Edit: as pointed out in a comment, this answer is kinda useless for C# programmers, as `CBool` is a VB-ism. It maps to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions::ToBoolean`, which is not suitable for general consumption. Which makes the XMLConvert class pointed out in the accepted answer an even better alternative.

Comment: I'm only seeing "CBool" defined for VB6, not for .NET.  It's possible that VB.NET is aliasing it to some Microsoft.VisualBasic.* method, but I'm using C#, so I'd need to know that underlying method to call.

Answer (score 0):

Sanitise the data before attempting to parse it:

```
 string InnerText = yourXmlNode.InnerText;    
if (InnerText.Equals("0"))
    InnerText = "false";
else if (InnerText.Equals("1"))
    InnerText = "true";
```

Any other entry than *true*, *false*, *0* or *1* will still throw a "Bad Format" exception (as it should be).

Answer (score 0):

```
return value === 'true' || Number(value)
```