# xsd:boolean element type accept "true" but not "True". How can I make it accept it?

Tags: xml, xsd, boolean

I am using xmllint --schema option to validate my XML that looks like this

```
<XML>
<Active>True</Active>
</XML>
```

In my schema file, I have following line that describes Active element.

```
<xsd:element name="Active" type="xs:boolean" />
```

When I run xmllint, I get error messages that says

> /tmp/schema_validation.xml:73: element
>   Active: Schemas validity error :
>   Element 'Active': 'True' is not a
>   valid value of the atomic type
>   'xs:boolean'.

When I change the XML to

```
<Active>true</Active>
```

Then the error message disappears.

So, it looks like xsd:boolean means it's all lowercase "true/false" but not "True/False" to xmllint.. My question is, how can I make xmllint to accept "True" for xsd:boolean type? Or is there different tools that I can use that will validate this XML? Changing the XML or schema is not my option at this point.

Thanks!

Comment: If changing the source XML or the schema is not an option, then I would suggest running the source XML through a transform that normalizes the boolean values to the proper XSD valid values.

Comment: I've thought of doing that, but I was scared to modify values that just happen to be "True". For eample, if a element called "Description" happens to contain value "True", then I don't want that to be converted to "true". I don't think there is any way to know which element to apply the normalization or not..

Comment: you need to go upstream: stop the generation of invalid XML at its source.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You cannot.

According to the [XML Schema specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean), a boolean is `true` or `false`.  `True` is not valid:

```
  3.2.2.1 Lexical representation
  An instance of a datatype that is defined as ·boolean· can have the 
  following legal literals {true, false, 1, 0}. 

  3.2.2.2 Canonical representation
  The canonical representation for boolean is the set of 
  literals {true, false}.
```

If the tool you are using truly validates against the XML Schema standard, then you cannot convince it to accept True for a boolean.

Comment: Thanks. It's good to know that there is absolutely no way to redefine xsd:boolean

Comment: To put it another way - if upstream software generates True for something defined as XML Schema boolean, then they are in fact not generating XML, but something else that happens to look similar. Their marketing department should then not claim they use XML, as they have now invalidated the point of using XML - the ability to reuse common parsers for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: I would differ with @Oskar here. There are tools that claim to generate XML but in fact don't, because what they generate is not well-formed. But here you seem to have upstream software that generates XML that *is* well-formed, but isn't valid according to its XML Schema. It's still XML. They just can't claim that it conforms to the XML Schema you're using.

Comment: The point is that the generator upstream uses a non-standard interpretation of the schema, that is why the OP needs a xmllint that accepts the same non-standard interpretation of the schema.

Comment: re: `OP needs a xmllint that accepts the same non-standard interpretation of the schema.` . There is no such thing. Tools don't get to "interpret" the schema.  The schema says "xsd:boolean" and that means, always, in every case, true or false.  Not True.  Not False. Not 1.  Not 0.  There is no room for "interpretation".  The generator is wrong, and broken.

Comment: Actually, 1, 0, are also valid values. See: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_misc.asp

Answer (score 55):

`xs:boolean` is predefined with regard to what kind of input it accepts. If you need something different, you have to define your own enumeration:

```
 <xs:simpleType name="my:boolean">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="True"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="False"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will request something likee this to be part of the schema so that I can work around this for now.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on Linux, or have cygwin available on Windows, you can run the input XML through a simple sed script that will replace `<Active>True</Active>` with `<Active>true</Active>`, like so:

```
cat <your XML file> | sed 'sX<Active>True</Active>X<Active>true</Active>X' | xmllint --schema -
```

If you're not, you can still use a non-validating xslt pocessor (xalan, saxon etc.) to run a simple xslt transformation on the input, and only then pipe it to xmllint.

What the xsl should contain something like below, for the example you listed above (the xslt processor should be 2.0 capable):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="XML">
        <xsl:for-each select="Active">
            <xsl:value-of select=" replace(current(), 'True','true')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Beware: I doubt there is any "simple `sed` script" robust enough to correctly do a substitution like this on an XML file --- yours is not.