# XML file, XSD schema Errors: Cannot resolve the name to a(n) 'type definition', Cannot find the declaration of element

Tags: xml, xsd

I am new to XML and XML Schema. I set up an XML file and an XML schema. I am not 100% familiar with namespaces.

I get the following errors in the XML schema:

- src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'childrenType' to a(n) 'type definition' component.xsd(src-resolve)
- src-resolve.4.1: Error resolving component 'childrenType'. It was detected that 'childrenType' has no namespace, but components with no target namespace are not referenceable from schema document 'file:///C:/XML/file_root.xsd'. If 'childrenType' is intended to have a namespace, perhaps a prefix needs to be provided. If it is intended that 'childrenType' has no namespace, then an 'import' without a "namespace" attribute should be added to 'file:///C:/XML/file_root.xsd'.xsd(src-resolve.4.1)

I get the following errors in the XML file:

- cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean'.xml(cvc-elt.1.a)

I do not know why 'childrenType' is not defined, because it is defined further down in the XSD document. I suspect that this is a namespace issue.

What I am trying to represent with the XSD schema:

- Representing a tree (BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean)
- The tree has one and only one root node
- Any node in the tree can be of only two types (NodeOperandType or NodeStringExpressionType)
- The node type, NodeOperandType, is the only node that can have children and it is required to have at least one child. NodeStringExpressionType cannot have any children.
- Node type NodeOperandType has the following elements: an operand (required), a test (required), and any children (as explained previously).
- Node type NodeStringExpressionType has the following required elements: a string expression, a test, a test string, and whether the test is case sensitive or not.

XSD File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:complexType name="NodeOperandType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:element name="operand" type="xs:string" /> -->
            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="children" type="childrenType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="NodeStringExpressionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:element name="string_expression" type="xs:string" /> -->
            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="test_string" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="case_sensitive" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="NodeType">
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="NodeOperand" type="NodeOperandType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xs:element name="NodeStringExpression" type="NodeStringExpressionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="childrenType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Node" type="NodeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Node" type="NodeType" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.w3schools.com file:///C:/XML/file_root.xsd">
    <Node>
        <NodeOperandType>
            <test>"or"</test>
            <children>
                <Node>
                    <NodeStringExpressionType>
                        <test>"include"</test>
                        <test_string>"simple"</test_string>
                        <case_sensitive>"true"</case_sensitive>
                    </NodeStringExpressionType>
                </Node>
                <Node>
                    <NodeStringExpressionType>
                        <test>"include"</test>
                        <test_string>"simple"</test_string>
                        <case_sensitive>"true"</case_sensitive>
                    </NodeStringExpressionType>
                </Node>
            </children>
        </NodeOperandType>
    </Node>
</BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean>
```

## Update after accepted answer:

The final XML file is shown below for future reference for anyone else visiting this question.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com file:///C:/XML/file_root.xsd">
    <Node>
        <NodeOperand>
            <test>"or"</test>
            <children>
                <Node>
                    <NodeStringExpression>
                        <test>"include"</test>
                        <test_string>"simple"</test_string>
                        <case_sensitive>true</case_sensitive>
                    </NodeStringExpression>
                </Node>
                <Node>
                    <NodeStringExpression>
                        <test>"include"</test>
                        <test_string>"simple"</test_string>
                        <case_sensitive>true</case_sensitive>
                    </NodeStringExpression>
                </Node>
            </children>
        </NodeOperand>
    </Node>
</BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean>
```

Comment: You have only defined complexTypes, you need to have the named elements (using your complexTypes) defined as well, e.g. <xsl:element name="BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean" type="BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean">. See https://www.w3schools.com/xml/el_complextype.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your edit, your question is answerable. But there remain several problems:

1. You define the type of the `<case_sensitive>` element as `xs:boolean`, but your content is wrapped in quotes, i.e., `"true"` instead of `true`. This is not valid; see [this SO answer regarding boolean values in XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1308534/1305969).
2. You are missing the namespace of all of your user defined types. So add an `xmlns` definition with the same value as your target namespace to your `xs:schema` element. So add

   ```
   xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com"
   ```

   to the `xs:schema` element. You need this to put the types into a namespace.
3. Now add the namespace prefix `tns`, to all of your user-defined types to reference them in the namespace, i.e. reference the type `childrenType` with `tns:childrenType`.
4. Finally, add a root element for your root type. So add

   ```
   <xs:element name="BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean" type="tns:BinaryExpressionTreeBooleanType" />
   ```

   to the XSD file, which requires you to change your `xs:complexType`'s name from `BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean` to `BinaryExpressionTreeBooleanType`.

Combining all of these changes, your XSD could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com">

    <xs:complexType name="NodeOperandType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:element name="operand" type="xs:string" /> -->
            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="children" type="tns:childrenType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="NodeStringExpressionType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <!-- <xs:element name="string_expression" type="xs:string" /> -->
            <xs:element name="test" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="test_string" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="case_sensitive" type="xs:boolean" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="NodeType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="NodeOperandType" type="tns:NodeOperandType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="NodeStringExpressionType" type="tns:NodeStringExpressionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="childrenType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="BinaryExpressionTreeBooleanType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Node" type="tns:NodeType" minOccurs="1"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:element name="BinaryExpressionTreeBoolean" type="tns:BinaryExpressionTreeBooleanType" />
</xs:schema>
```

And this XSD-1.0 file can validate your above XML after your change all of your boolean string values from `"true"` to `true` and from `"false"` to `false`. If you cannot change this, you have three options:

1. Apply a pre-processing XSLT file that changes these values to the valid ones. This can, for example, be achieved with the following template:

   ```
   <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3schools.com" version="1.0">
       <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

       <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
           <xsl:copy>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
           </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="tns:case_sensitive/text()">
           <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&quot;','')" />
       </xsl:template>

   </xsl:stylesheet>
   ```
2. Change the type of the element `<case_sensitive>` to `xs:string`.
3. Express the type in an `xs:pattern`. To do this, add the following type:

   ```
   <xs:simpleType name="caseType">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
           <xs:pattern value='true|false|\"true\"|\"false\"|1|0'></xs:pattern> 
       </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
   ```

   and then reference this type in the related element:

   ```
   <xs:element name="case_sensitive" type="tns:caseType" />
   ```

After doing all this, the *validation will succeed*.

Comment: Thanks for the great and detailed answer. I had a question though, why was
`<xs:element name="NodeOperand" type="tns:NodeOperandType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />`
changed to 
`<xs:element name="NodeOperandType" type="tns:NodeOperandType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />`
where the `name="NodeOperand"` was changed to `name="NodeOperandType"`.


Same for `name="NodeStringExpression"` changed to `name="NodeStringExpressionType"`.

Comment: In your updated XML sample the elements were named `NodeOperandType` and `NodeStringExpressionType`, respectively. Hence I named the `xs:element`s like this. That's all, nothing spectacular. BTW the element and the type can have the same name.